# cargar datos en select al llenar los input desde js

Tags: javascript, html

Buen dia, Practicamente tengo un problema al mandar el "value" al Select, se que el "value" es correcto, pero no se porque no lo admite html desde js. el valor enviado por  json[0].pro_pais_id  es correcto es "1" ya lo verifique. lo que yo quiero es que al cargar los datos de la pagina tambien se actualicen los selects y no queden con la informacion por default de "seleccione una opcion" debe cargar la unica opcion q tengo en el select que es Mexico. espero me haya dado a entender  y les agradezco muchisimo de antemano gracias

pd ya intente varias cosas como
1 - getelementbytag
2 - SelectedIndex = al json[0]
3 - crear una funcion con el selectedIndex
4 - document.getElementById(id).options[json[0].selected = 'selected';

```
function mostrarProveedor() {
if (document.getElementById('txtBusquedaProveedor').value == '') {
    alert('Escriba para buscar un proveedor');
}
else {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("id", document.getElementById('txtBusquedaProveedor').value)
    xhr.open('POST', '/Proveedor/MostrarProveedores', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        let json = JSON.parse(respuesta);
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("codigo").value = json[0].pro_codigo;
            document.getElementById("irs").value = json[0].pro_IRS;
            document.getElementById("tipoPersona").value = json[0].pro_tipoPersona;
            document.getElementById("nombre").value = json[0].pro_nombre;
            document.getElementById("paterno").value = json[0].pro_apellidoPaterno;
            document.getElementById("materno").value = json[0].pro_apellidomaterno;
            document.getElementById("paisProveedor").value = json[0].pro_pais_id;
            document.getElementById("municipioProveedor").value = json[0].pro_municipio_id;
            document.getElementById("estadoProveedor").value = json[0].pro_estado_id;
            document.getElementById("cpProveedor").value = json[0].pro_codigoPostal;
            document.getElementById("coloniaProveedor").value = json[0].pro_colonia;
            document.getElementById("calleProveedor").value = json[0].pro_calle;
            document.getElementById("exteriorProveedor").value = json[0].pro_numeroExterior;
            document.getElementById("interiorProveedor").value = json[0].pro_numeroInterior;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#informacionProveedor>div>label')).length; i++) {
            Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#informacionProveedor>div>label'))[i].setAttribute('class', 'active');
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#pestaniaDireccionProveedor>div>label')).length; i++) {
            Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#pestaniaDireccionProveedor>div>label'))[i].setAttribute('class', 'active');
        }
    }

    }
}
xhr.send(data);
```

}

```
<div id="direccion" class="col s12 pestaniaBorder">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="col s12">
                    <div id="pestaniaDireccionProveedor" class="selectDividir">
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l4 selectDividir">
                            <select id="paisProveedor">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion</option>
                                <option value="1">Mexico</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Pais</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l4 selectDividir">
                            <select id="estadoProveedor">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion</option>
                                <option value="1">Baja California</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Estado</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l4 selectDividir">
                            <select id="municipioProveedor">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion</option>
                                <option value="1">Tijuana</option>
                                <option value="2">Mexicali</option>
                                <option value="3">Ensenada</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Municipio</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l4 selectDividir">
                            <select id="estadoSagarpaProveedor">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion</option>
                                <option value="1">Baja California</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Estado Sagarpa</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l4 selectDividir">
                            <select id="municipioSagarpaProveedor">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione una opcion</option>
                                <option value="1">Tijuana</option>
                                <option value="2">Mexicali</option>
                                <option value="3">Ensenada</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Municipio Sagarpa</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l4 selectDividir">
                            <input id="calleProveedor" type="text" class="validate">
                            <label for="calle">Calle</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3 selectDividir">
                            <input id="cpProveedor" type="text" class="validate">
                            <label for="cp">Codigo Postal</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3 selectDividir">
                            <input id="coloniaProveedor" type="text" class="validate">
                            <label for="colonia">Colonia</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3 selectDividir">
                            <input id="exteriorProveedor" type="text" class="validate">
                            <label for="exterior">Numero Exterior</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l3 selectDividir">
                            <input id="interiorProveedor" type="text" class="validate">
                            <label for="interior">Numero Interior</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de tu json? Por ejemplo, si tienes el id del país y el nombre podrías agregarlo al select de esta forma:  `document.getElementById("paisProveedor").appendChild(new Option(json[0].pro_pais_nombre, json[0].pro_pais_id));`, pero eso está en dependencia de la estructura de tu json.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar código como texto, tanto HTML como Javascript que has intentado y un ejemplo del JSON que recibes.

Comment: Listo ya añadi el codigo. gracias

Comment: ¿Recibes más de un proveedor? Porque tienes ciclo para recorrer los resultados `for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)`, sin embargo, nunca usas el índice `i`, accedes a todos los datos con `json[0].nombre_de_propiedad`. Antes de `var respuesta = ...` agrega `console.log(xhr.responseText);` para ver lo que estás recibiendo. Edita la pregunta para agregar lo que aparece en la consola, aunque me temo que el problema es que estás usando dos veces `JSON.parse()` y nunca entra al ciclo.

Comment: @Triby  esto arroja el console.log(xhr.responseText); ya agregue la imagen, como trabajo en un servidor se me complica sacar el codigo

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a lo que obtienes en consola, el error es porque tratas de interpretar dos veces como JSON:

```
    // Este funciona sin problema
    var respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    // Este debería mostrar un error en consola, porque "respuesta" ya es un JSON
    let json = JSON.parse(respuesta);
```

Como estás recibiendo solo un resultado, no es necesario el ciclo, en todo caso, solo un *if* para confirmar que se recibió un registro:

```
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    // Declarar variable
    let json;
    // Interpretar JSON solo una vez, con validación
    try {
        json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    } catch(e) {
        // No es un JSON válido, mostrar error
        console.log(e);
        // Finalizar ejecución
        return;
    }
    // ¿Se recibió un registro?
    if(json.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("codigo").value = json[0].pro_codigo;
        document.getElementById("irs").value = json[0].pro_IRS;
        document.getElementById("tipoPersona").value = json[0].pro_tipoPersona;
        document.getElementById("nombre").value = json[0].pro_nombre;
        document.getElementById("paterno").value = json[0].pro_apellidoPaterno;
        document.getElementById("materno").value = json[0].pro_apellidomaterno;
        document.getElementById("paisProveedor").value = json[0].pro_pais_id;
        document.getElementById("municipioProveedor").value = json[0].pro_municipio_id;
        document.getElementById("estadoProveedor").value = json[0].pro_estado_id;
        document.getElementById("cpProveedor").value = json[0].pro_codigoPostal;
        document.getElementById("coloniaProveedor").value = json[0].pro_colonia;
        document.getElementById("calleProveedor").value = json[0].pro_calle;
        document.getElementById("exteriorProveedor").value = json[0].pro_numeroExterior;
        document.getElementById("interiorProveedor").value = json[0].pro_numeroInterior;
    }
    // En lugar de crear ciclos puedes obtener todas las etiquetas y,
    // usando funciones flecha, puedes recorrerlas para asignar clase
    document.querySelectorAll('#informacionProveedor>div>label').forEach(label => {
        label.setAttribute('class', 'active');
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('#pestaniaDireccionProveedor>div>label').forEach(label => {
        label.setAttribute('class', 'active');
    });
} else {
    // No se recibieron resultados o hubo error
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
```